# touchpad scrolling twitching

Tags: scrolling

Recently GTK3 applications, such as gedit and xfce4-terminal, have started intermittently skipping between smooth sections when scrolling. I find it really disorientating when navigating code and terminal output.
I've uploaded a video of the effect here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ag9xp.jpg

In the first part I'm trying to scroll smoothly in xfce4-terminal. Both up and downward scrolling has smooth sections punctuated by regular jumps.
In the second part I show that in brave browser there are no such skips, at least demonstrating that this isn't a hardware issue or problem with the touchpad edge scrolling input.

It didn't used to do this, but I'm at a total loss as to what changed.
Does anyone know what's up with this, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that it's a [known bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/704), at least 4 years old, which shows up if you have multiple input methods installed. Uninstalling `ibus` (which had been pulled in by Zoom) and ensuring no other input methods were installed recovered smooth scrolling again.